# XSLT-1.0 to establish a one-one relationship

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I generated a report which displays records in one to many style. However, I need to display them as one-one. I used the XSLT to transform the source XML but, it did not work.

I developed this XSLT to transform the XML.
However, it does not work.

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Records count="2">
    <Record contentId="1442264" levelId="98" levelGuid="b085b230-e20f-41df- 
a849-f5d6811447ea" moduleId="167" parentId="0">
        <Record contentId="1608202" levelId="155" levelGuid="20b8e343-96c0-4aed- 
804c-7e40b489f31b" moduleId="537" parentId="0">
            <Field id="17169" guid="ed20bfb9-d2e9-44c2-9b22-5e39d26beae4" 
type="6">16913</Field>
            <Field id="27556" guid="d378d42e-42da-4a23-906a-722fcb7d761e" 
type="6">1608202</Field>
        </Record>
        <Record contentId="1608204" levelId="155" levelGuid="20b8e343-96c0-4aed- 
804c-7e40b489f31b" moduleId="537" parentId="0">
            <Field id="17169" guid="ed20bfb9-d2e9-44c2-9b22-5e39d26beae4" 
type="6">16915</Field>
            <Field id="27556" guid="d378d42e-42da-4a23-906a-722fcb7d761e" 
type="6">1608204</Field>
        </Record>
        <Field id="2260" guid="a69370c5-b6a7-4e20-a073-dd6bbd131e43" 
type="6">1442264</Field>
    </Record>
    <Record contentId="1445144" levelId="98" levelGuid="b085b230-e20f-41df- 
a849-f5d6811447ea" moduleId="167" parentId="0">
        <Record contentId="1608203" levelId="155" levelGuid="20b8e343-96c0-4aed- 
804c-7e40b489f31b" moduleId="537" parentId="0">
            <Field id="17169" guid="ed20bfb9-d2e9-44c2-9b22-5e39d26beae4" 
type="6">16914</Field>
            <Field id="27556" guid="d378d42e-42da-4a23-906a-722fcb7d761e" 
type="6">1608203</Field>
        </Record>
        <Record contentId="1608205" levelId="155" levelGuid="20b8e343-96c0-4aed- 
804c-7e40b489f31b" moduleId="537" parentId="0">
            <Field id="17169" guid="ed20bfb9-d2e9-44c2-9b22-5e39d26beae4" 
type="6">16916</Field>
            <Field id="27556" guid="d378d42e-42da-4a23-906a-722fcb7d761e" 
type="6">1608205</Field>
        </Record>
        <Field id="2260" guid="a69370c5-b6a7-4e20-a073-dd6bbd131e43" 
type="6">1445144</Field>
    </Record>
    <Metadata>
        <FieldDefinitions>
            <FieldDefinition id="2260" guid="a69370c5-b6a7-4e20-a073-dd6bbd131e43" 
name="Issue ID" alias="Finding_ID" />
            <FieldDefinition id="17169" guid="ed20bfb9-d2e9-44c2-9b22-5e39d26beae4" 
name="CAP ID" alias="Remediation_Plan_ID" />
            <FieldDefinition id="17182" guid="e950ebab-1bf6-4fc8-818b-88a54fd12f89" 
name="CAP Title" alias="Name" />
            <FieldDefinition id="27556" guid="d378d42e-42da-4a23-906a-722fcb7d761e" 
name="X - Tracking ID" alias="X__Tracking_ID" />
        </FieldDefinitions>
    </Metadata>
    <LevelCounts>
        <LevelCount id="98" guid="b085b230-e20f-41df-a849-f5d6811447ea" count="2" 
/>
        <LevelCount id="155" guid="20b8e343-96c0-4aed-804c-7e40b489f31b" 
count="4" />
    </LevelCounts>
</Records>
```

And this is my XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl" xmlns="http://www.archer-tech.com/">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <ArcherRecords>
            <xsl:for-each select="Records/Record/Field[@guid='b085b230-e20f-41df- 
 a849-f5d6811447ea']/Reference">
                <ArcherRecord>
                    <IssueID>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </IssueID>
                    <CAPID>
                        <xsl:value-of select="../../Field[@guid='ed20bfb9-d2e9-44c2-9b22- 
 5e39d26beae4']"/>
                    </CAPID>
                    <XTrackingID>
                        <xsl:value-of select="../../Field[@guid='d378d42e-42da- 
 4a23-906a-722fcb7d761e']"/>
                    </XTrackingID>
                </ArcherRecord>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </ArcherRecords>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My Input is:

```
Issue ID                  CAP ID          X - Tracking ID
Issue-1442264             CAP-16913       1608202
                          CAP-16915       1608204
Issue-1445144             CAP-16914       1608203
                          CAP-16916       1608205
```

And the expected output is:

```
Issue ID           CAP ID       X - Tracking ID
Issue-1442264      CAP-16913    1608202
Issue-1442264      CAP-16915    1608204
Issue-1445144      CAP-16914    1608203
Issue-1445144      CAP-16916    1608205
```

The actual output is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <ArcherRecords xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns="http://www.archer-tech.com/"/>
```

Comment: Input and Expected formatting is not right. They are four rows (2 for each record).In Input rows, Issue ID displays only once instead of twice. In expected, issue id displayed twice

Comment: I don't understand your expected output, but when you are transforming a tree structure into a list structure you need to iterate over the deepest level (ie. `CAP ID` or `X - Tracking ID`)

Answer (score 0):

The main reason why your XSLT is failing is that both your XML and XSLT have improper whitespace-handling. Due to this, the expressions do not match!

**The solution is *fixing your linebreaks*!**

For example:
Your relevant `levelGuid` attribute contains a line-break and some spaces which makes it (nearly) impossible to be matched by the connected XPath expression's string value.

So you'll have to face the inconvenient task of correcting the line-breaks of your XML.

---

After you fixed your line-break situation, the following XSLT-1.0 code will give you some useful output:

```
<xsl:template match="/Records">
    <ArcherRecords>
        <xsl:for-each select="Record[@levelGuid='b085b230-e20f-41df-a849-f5d6811447ea']">
            <ArcherRecord>
                <IssueID>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@contentId"/>
                </IssueID>
                <xsl:for-each select="Record">
                    <CAPID>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Field[@guid='ed20bfb9-d2e9-44c2-9b22-5e39d26beae4']"/>
                    </CAPID>
                    <XTrackingID>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Field[@guid='d378d42e-42da-4a23-906a-722fcb7d761e']"/>
                    </XTrackingID>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </ArcherRecord>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </ArcherRecords>
</xsl:template>
```

**Its output is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArcherRecords xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:arch="http://www.archer-tech.com/">
    <ArcherRecord>
        <IssueID>1442264</IssueID>
        <CAPID>16913</CAPID>
        <XTrackingID>1608202</XTrackingID>
        <CAPID>16915</CAPID>
        <XTrackingID>1608204</XTrackingID>
    </ArcherRecord>
    <ArcherRecord>
        <IssueID>1445144</IssueID>
        <CAPID>16914</CAPID>
        <XTrackingID>1608203</XTrackingID>
        <CAPID>16916</CAPID>
        <XTrackingID>1608205</XTrackingID>
    </ArcherRecord>
</ArcherRecords>
```

This is the answer to your question.
Now, the task remains to get a pure text output.
And a template to create the desired output is:

```
<xsl:output method="text" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/Records">
    <xsl:text>Issue ID&#x9;CAP ID&#x9;&#x9;X - Tracking ID&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="Record[@levelGuid='b085b230-e20f-41df-a849-f5d6811447ea']">
        <xsl:for-each select="Record">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('Issue-',../@contentId)"/><xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('CAP-',Field[@guid='ed20bfb9-d2e9-44c2-9b22-5e39d26beae4'])"/><xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="Field[@guid='d378d42e-42da-4a23-906a-722fcb7d761e']"/>
            <xsl:text>&#x9;&#xa;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

**Its output is:**

```
Issue ID        CAP ID          X - Tracking ID
Issue-1442264   CAP-16913       1608202
Issue-1442264   CAP-16915       1608204
Issue-1445144   CAP-16914       1608203
Issue-1445144   CAP-16916       1608205
```

Comment: Thanks zx485 for the response. Lei has provided condensed xslt above. It worked fine. The challenge I have now is fixing the xml. I do not have control on the xml as I am getting it from a source. Any thoughts on fixing the xml via xslt? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to find the `one` of your one-many XML relationship, then iterate the `many` to generate new XML element.

**.xsl**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl" xmlns="http://www.archer-tech.com/">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <ArcherRecords>
            <xsl:for-each select='//Record[@levelGuid="b085b230-e20f-41df-a849-f5d6811447ea"]'>
              <xsl:param name="issueid">
                    <xsl:value-of select="Field[@guid='a69370c5-b6a7-4e20-a073-dd6bbd131e43']"></xsl:value-of>
                </xsl:param>
                <xsl:for-each select="Record">
                    <ArcherRecord>
                        <IssueID>Issue-<xsl:value-of select="$issueid"></xsl:value-of>
                        </IssueID>
                        <CAPID>CAP-<xsl:value-of select="Field[@guid='ed20bfb9-d2e9-44c2-9b22-5e39d26beae4']" />
                        </CAPID>
                        <XTrackingID>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Field[@guid='d378d42e-42da-4a23-906a-722fcb7d761e']" />
                        </XTrackingID>
                    </ArcherRecord>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </ArcherRecords>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result according to your XML goes to

```xml
<ArcherRecords>
    <ArcherRecord>
        <IssueID>Issue-1442264</IssueID>
        <CAPID>CAP-16913</CAPID>
        <XTrackingID>1608202</XTrackingID>
    </ArcherRecord>
    <ArcherRecord>
        <IssueID>Issue-1442264</IssueID>
        <CAPID>CAP-16915</CAPID>
        <XTrackingID>1608204</XTrackingID>
    </ArcherRecord>
    <ArcherRecord>
        <IssueID>Issue-1445144</IssueID>
        <CAPID>CAP-16914</CAPID>
        <XTrackingID>1608203</XTrackingID>
    </ArcherRecord>
    <ArcherRecord>
        <IssueID>Issue-1445144</IssueID>
        <CAPID>CAP-16916</CAPID>
        <XTrackingID>1608205</XTrackingID>
    </ArcherRecord>
</ArcherRecords>
```

---

Fixed linebreaks XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Records count="2">
    <Record contentId="1442264" levelId="98" levelGuid="b085b230-e20f-41df-a849-f5d6811447ea" moduleId="167" parentId="0">
        <Record contentId="1608202" levelId="155" levelGuid="20b8e343-96c0-4aed-804c-7e40b489f31b" moduleId="537" parentId="0">
            <Field id="17169" guid="ed20bfb9-d2e9-44c2-9b22-5e39d26beae4" type="6">16913</Field>
            <Field id="27556" guid="d378d42e-42da-4a23-906a-722fcb7d761e" type="6">1608202</Field>
        </Record>
        <Record contentId="1608204" levelId="155" levelGuid="20b8e343-96c0-4aed-804c-7e40b489f31b" moduleId="537" parentId="0">
            <Field id="17169" guid="ed20bfb9-d2e9-44c2-9b22-5e39d26beae4" type="6">16915</Field>
            <Field id="27556" guid="d378d42e-42da-4a23-906a-722fcb7d761e" type="6">1608204</Field>
        </Record>
        <Field id="2260" guid="a69370c5-b6a7-4e20-a073-dd6bbd131e43" type="6">1442264</Field>
    </Record>
    <Record contentId="1445144" levelId="98" levelGuid="b085b230-e20f-41df-a849-f5d6811447ea" moduleId="167" parentId="0">
        <Record contentId="1608203" levelId="155" levelGuid="20b8e343-96c0-4aed-804c-7e40b489f31b" moduleId="537" parentId="0">
            <Field id="17169" guid="ed20bfb9-d2e9-44c2-9b22-5e39d26beae4" type="6">16914</Field>
            <Field id="27556" guid="d378d42e-42da-4a23-906a-722fcb7d761e" type="6">1608203</Field>
        </Record>
        <Record contentId="1608205" levelId="155" levelGuid="20b8e343-96c0-4aed-804c-7e40b489f31b" moduleId="537" parentId="0">
            <Field id="17169" guid="ed20bfb9-d2e9-44c2-9b22-5e39d26beae4" type="6">16916</Field>
            <Field id="27556" guid="d378d42e-42da-4a23-906a-722fcb7d761e" type="6">1608205</Field>
        </Record>
        <Field id="2260" guid="a69370c5-b6a7-4e20-a073-dd6bbd131e43" type="6">1445144</Field>
    </Record>
    <Metadata>
        <FieldDefinitions>
            <FieldDefinition id="2260" guid="a69370c5-b6a7-4e20-a073-dd6bbd131e43" name="Issue ID" alias="Finding_ID" />
            <FieldDefinition id="17169" guid="ed20bfb9-d2e9-44c2-9b22-5e39d26beae4" name="CAP ID" alias="Remediation_Plan_ID" />
            <FieldDefinition id="17182" guid="e950ebab-1bf6-4fc8-818b-88a54fd12f89" name="CAP Title" alias="Name" />
            <FieldDefinition id="27556" guid="d378d42e-42da-4a23-906a-722fcb7d761e" name="X - Tracking ID" alias="X__Tracking_ID" />
        </FieldDefinitions>
    </Metadata>
    <LevelCounts>
        <LevelCount id="98" guid="b085b230-e20f-41df-a849-f5d6811447ea" count="2" />
        <LevelCount id="155" guid="20b8e343-96c0-4aed-804c-7e40b489f31b" count="4" />
    </LevelCounts>
</Records>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried this xsl and an error popped up . "Error: net.sf.saxon.s9api.SaxonApiException: Errors were reported during stylesheet compilation"... Could you please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Thanks Lei, let me try using your tool.

Comment: I ran with the link you provided and the result is : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ArcherRecords xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.archer-tech.com/"/>

Comment: Sorry I am not sure what I am missing here. any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks Lei

Comment: @Kumar I know the reason is your XML with new lines break the ID! I fixed your XML with new edit

Comment: @Kumar Test URL: http://www.utilities-online.info/xsltransformation/#.XJrYZ-vYqi5

Comment: oh..k. the linebreak..the XML I am getting is from a source which I do not control, can that XML with line breaks be fixed via xslt?

Comment: @Kumar hmmm, it's the error from server end. I don't think you should fix that. Just use the ID with new line. For example,` <xsl:for-each select='//Record[@levelGuid="b085b230-e20f-41df-a849-f5d6811447ea"]'>` change the id with new line as the original XML, then it works.